# Setting environment variables for scons to use globally on my system

Tags: build, environment-variables, scons

Is there any way to set environment variables for my system which scons will use, without me having to change the SConstruct file? For example, I would like to use MinGW instead of VC++ for my C++ builds on Windows. I can, of course, do this in my SConstruct file:

```
env = Environment(tools = ['mingw'])
```

But if I do that, then I'm editing things into my build files that make it specific to my particular system configuration. That defeats the whole purpose of a portable build system, in my opinion. If I upload that as part of my repository for others to build, they may not be using MinGW. They may want to use VC++, or Clang, and I don't think they should have to modify the build file (or anything else in the repository for that matter) in order to build the program or library. Ideally, anyone with in an environment with a functional C++ toolchain and scons installed *should* be able to just type `scons` on the command line, and things should go smoothly for them. Isn't that the (or a) goal of scons? Or am I misunderstanding its purpose?

Another thing is paths. The above line is not even enough, I have to still import the path to the MinGW binaries. I've read the justification for this. But it's just more system specific information which I have to put in my build files, which may be used by others where the chosen paths are not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have indeed understood the purpose of SCons regarding it being portable and multi-platform :)

The issue here is if you have multiple compilers to choose from on your system, how to tell SCons which one to use. By default SCons will look for and use the compiler specific to your system (VC++ on windows or g++ on linux for example).

I can think of at least 2 ways of telling SCons which compiler to use, both of which will require extra logic in the build scripts, but can be done in a portable manner:

1. Environment variables
2. command line arguments

I would consider always using the system-specific compiler unless the user invokes scons with arguments/variables instructing it to use a different one.

If you choose to use Environment variables, you can just use standard python code, as follows, and explained [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#sect-external-environments):

```
import os

some_var = os.environ['SOME_VAR']
```

Or, if you choose to use command line arguments, you can find everything you need [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-command-line).

Personally, I would prefer command line options, as its more explicit than env vars. With env vars, the users may get undesired results due to env vars they didnt realize were set.

Comment: But doesn't this require a modification to the SConstruct file? Since I asked the question, I've learned about the "site_init.py" file, which will allow me to set up some system specific settings. But I can't figure out how it will allow me to set the default options for the Environment object that the SConstuct file creates.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, with this answer you would need to modify the build scripts, but I understood from your question you were looking for a portable way to set the compiler and could indeed edit the build scripts. If you're going to edit the site_init.py, consider setting the DefaultEnvironment as explained here: http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idm12919064

Comment: No, the point is to not have to modify build scripts. When I speak of a "portable build system", to me that means that, ideally, if you create a project that builds and runs on your system (using portable code), I should be able to build and run the project on a completely different system, with no changes whatsoever to your project, which includes the build files. Unfortunately, scons makes too many assumptions on my part for this to work. I don't mind telling scons how to compile C++ on my system, but I want to do it only once, and I want it to apply to all projects, mine or someone else's.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ok, I understand now. You can indeed build with the same SCons build scripts and portable c++ source code on multiple platforms. What you cant do is expect SCons (or any other build system) to automatically know which compiler you want when there is more than one available.

Comment: But I don't need or want scons to automatically know which compiler I want to use.  I just want that decision about which compiler to use to be taken away from the person writing the SConscript file, and given to the person building the project, i.e. the person who is familiar with the computer which scons is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the file `site_init.py` in one of these directories:

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE/Application Data/scons/site_scons
%USERPROFILE%/Local Settings/Application Data/scons/site_scons
%APPDATA%/scons/site_scons
%HOME%/.scons/site_scons
./site_scons
```

In that file, add a line like this:

```
DefaultEnvironment(tools = ['mingw'])
```

or maybe this:

```
DefaultEnvironment(tools = ['default', 'mingw'])
```